# warping ratchet with stunnel

Tags: ssl, stunnel, ratchet

I have ratchet webSocket server running and it works well. 
the problem is that some of the connections are closing right after the handshake.

after searching stackOverflow and google I found out that I should use wss, because using ssl will prevent the connections from being closed. after some more reading I found that wss is not implemented yet in ratchet, and that the solution is to warp ratchet with stunnel. I searched again for help on how to implement this but found non .

how do I warp ratchet with stunnel? is there a better way to solve this problem?
I'm really a newbie will all the ssl issue.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up your ratchet websocket to accept only local connections:

```
$webSock = new Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '127.0.0.1'); // local connections only
$session = $this->getContainer()->get('session.provider');
$server = new IoServer(new WsServer($session), $webSock, $loop);
```

Generate a server certificate. Nice instructions for ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html).

Now install stunnel. Ubuntu instructions [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/stunnel-universal-ssl-tunnel-for-network-daemons.html).

Configure stunnel to use the new certificate and accept connections on a secure port and tunnel them to your websocket server:

```
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
key = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
...
[websockets]
accept = 8443
connect = 8080
```

Start stunnel, and you should be off to the races.